# Is there a way to improve Rs speed (for-loop)?

Tags: r, for-loop, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm using a basic for-loop, which takes like 10 minutes to compute:

```
for (t in 2:outsample) {
  ugfit_sged <- ugarchfit(spec = ug_spec_sged, data = rIBM[1:(insample+t-1)])
  coef_sged[t,] <- coef(ugfit_sged)
}
```

Fortunately, I'm happy with the results, but it's still annoying that the code takes so long. When I look at the task manager, I see that RStudio barely uses any CPU or RAM. This makes me wonder whether this is normal or whether there is a way to increase Rs usage of the CPU, which I hope would make it faster.

I have used:

```
startDate = as.Date("2007-01-03") #Specify period of time we are interested in
endDate = as.Date("2018-04-30")

insample <- 2500
outsample <- 350
T <- insample + outsample

#Package: Quantmod
getSymbols("IBM", from = startDate, to = endDate)
rIBM <- dailyReturn(IBM)

#Package: rugarch
ug_spec_sged <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)),
                          mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,0), include.mean = FALSE),
                          distribution.model = "sged")

coef_sged <- matrix(nrow = outsample, ncol = length(coef(ugfit_sged)))
colnames(coef_sged) <- names(coef(ugfit_sged))
rownames(coef_sged) <- c(1:outsample)
coef_sged[1,] <- coef(ugfit_sged)
```

Comment: Can you please show a small reproducible example so that somebody can test it

Comment: @akrun I edited the question. Is this helpful?

Comment: `Error: object 'coef_sged' not found`

Comment: @Armali , I updated the section of the code to unclude the definition of coef_sged

Comment: you'll probably have to parallelize this.  See e.g. `?parLapply`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look promising. Let's measure:

```
system.time({for (t in 2:outsample) {
  ugfit_sged <- ugarchfit(spec = ug_spec_sged, data = rIBM[1:(insample+t-1)])
  coef_sged[t,] <- coef(ugfit_sged)
}})
#   user  system elapsed 
#431.305   0.108 432.105 
(431.305+0.108)/349
#[1] 1.23614
```

One loop cycle here took a bit more than 1.2 seconds.

```
system.time({ugfit_sged <- ugarchfit(spec = ug_spec_sged, data = head(rIBM, insample+2-1))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.191   0.000   1.195
```

A single call of `ugarchfit` even with the shortest array slice took nearly 1.2 seconds. So, most of the time is spent inside `ugarchfit`; any significant optimization would have to be done there, if at all possible. The loop overhead is negligible - after all, it's only 349 runs.

> I've read that some packages allow for parallel computing. Do you think that could speed the process up a bit? (I haven't worked with parallel computing before)

Neither have I (in R), but it might be relatively straightforward with [mclapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html) … not thoroughly tested:

```
library(parallel)
system.time(mclapply(2:outsample, function(t) {
  ugfit_sged <- ugarchfit(spec = ug_spec_sged, data = rIBM[1:(insample+t-1)])
  coef_sged[t,] <- coef(ugfit_sged)
}, mc.cores=detectCores()))  # maybe you want to use fewer than all cores
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've read that some packages allow for parallel computing. Do you think that could speed the process up a bit? (I haven't worked with parallel computing before)

Comment: I added something you could try (RStudio Cloud was too unreliable for me).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in windows, but I will continue to look into it. Thanks